# Universal links not working in iOS 12.2 , 12.3

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, ios-universal-links

I recently implemented universal links in iOS. It works fine in iOS version 12.1 and below but fails to redirect back to the app in iOS 12.2 and 12.3.

Issue in 12.2 and higher:
The browser doesn’t redirects back to the app but I do get a banner(with an ‘OPEN’ button) in the browser to open the content in the app.

Even when I copy the link in Notes and long press it, it shows me the option to open the link in my app. 
I read in some article that there is a possibility that universal links get disabled and by choosing the option to ‘Open in {myApp}’ re-enables it. But this is not the case.
Despite trying the above method, universal links still doesn’t works the way it should.

Pre-Checks:

- AASA link is verified through Branch.io validator
- Applink is registered in entitlements.plist file
- Proper handling of redirected url is performed (Note that I do get a banner in the browser to open the url in my app and upon clicking
  on it, the app functions as it needs to)

Is there any change from 12.2 that I am missing?
I went through the release notes and was unable to find anything about universal links.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I saw some people meet the same problem with you and this may caused by Apple in version above 12.2.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Can you please share any link where we can see this is reported as a bug to apple.

Comment: I am not sure if it is a problem of Apple, But I saw several people meet this problem recently. I didn't collect these links and I would test it later on my side.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT That would be great if you can check from your side.

Comment: Any updates on this? We're having the same problem

Comment: @EndiveauJambon sadly no.

Comment: any updates on this? Having the same problem here

Comment: @chgsilva the issue magically resolved itself for me, I assumed it was a problem on their end.

Comment: @EndiveauJambon Is it resolved with a latest ios update ?

Comment: @chgsilva no it resolved itself the next day without me doing anything. Same iOs same branch sdk, it just went away.